# Trebuchet vs City Walls

Tags: warfare

About how long would a besieging army need to open a reasonably exploitable gap in a 30 foot thick (at the base) stone wall using counterweight Trebuchet's? 
Lets say they want to be able to get a line of footmen through with ladders.

Comment: a few days... it depends on how many Trebuchets are used and what  ammo they are using. update your Question with more details for a better answer

Comment: You seem to have some very different aims in mind - either you storm the walls with ladders (in which case a volley or two of rock shards and debris just before you attack would seem to be in order) or you bring down the walls and then push the breach on the ground (in which case undermining is, frankly, loads easier). Alternatively, a *besieging* army would sit at long range and wait, whittling the garrison down; in that case "how long" is "until they give up or sally against you".

Comment: I think you need to do more basic research yourself (trebuchet's are well documented in historical castle sieges).  A typical heavy siege trebuchet might fire a 30 kg payload as far as 100m and the projectile could be traveling at something like100 km/hr - that's a lot of damage.  Medieval walls were often attacked in different ways (see "undermining") and by siege tower.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a story in real world history, not about building fictional world.

Comment: agreed, there is no fictional elements at work here